# GIMP: How is this filter called?

Tags: gimp, style-identification, filter

I recently used this filter .. but I forgot its name, can you help me finding it out please?

Here the screenshot of it:

[image]

I mean the filter of the yellow and brown layer, how is it called? I can't find it anymore....

I tried pixelize etc. but this is not what I id before, but I have no idea. I hope you can find the correct filter. I'm using GIMP v. 2.8 on Linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the [**Cubism**](http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-cubism.html) filter to me

[image: Cubism filter]